# way too keep function that called by event listener in execution

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i try to make a button that get the time now ,put it in

element and updated every one second using the event listener the problem that the time disappear immediately

```
var time 
function updateTime(){
    time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML=time
    setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
 }
 
 document.getElementById("btnclock").addEventListener("click", updateTime);


html 
<button id="btnclock"> Start Clock</button>
        <p id='showtime'> </p>
```

Comment: it looks like you are adding another setinterval each time the function get called, so in a couple of seconds, you will get hunders of calls

Comment: @codingStarter 
more explaintion PLz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you click the button, `updateTime` function calls `setInterval(updateTime, 1000)` which creates a timer. The timer calls `updateTime` function every second. But `updateTime` creates another timer while the first one is still running. So in fact what is happening is that every second every running timer creates a new timer so after 10 seconds you will have 1024 timers running at the same time. This is obviously not what you want.

Try something like this:

```js
var timer = 0;

function startTimer() {
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
  }
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = 0;
}

function updateTime() {
  var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("show-time").innerHTML = time;
}

document.getElementById("start-clock").addEventListener("click", startTimer);
document.getElementById("stop-clock").addEventListener("click", stopTimer);
```

```html
<button id="start-clock">Start Clock</button>
<button id="stop-clock">Stop Clock</button>
<p id="show-time"></p>
```

It is important to destroy the timer when you no longer need it. Function `clearInterval` does it.

Comment: actually you will have much more, after 10 second you will have 2^10=1024 timers, after just one minute, you will have a huge amount of timers.

Comment: @codingStarter you are right, shame on me!

Comment: ohh right,i caught it
i try this and also didn't work why?
``` var time 

 var item =document.getElementById('showtime')
 function updateTime(){
    time =new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    item.innerHTML=time
     
 }
 document.getElementById("btnclock").addEventListener("click", ()=>setInterval(updateTime, 1000));
```

Comment: what doesnt work? does it display anything at all?

Comment: @codingStarter no

Comment: log the item variable to the console inside the update function, is it undefind? if the code get executed before the page is bulit, it wont find the p element. if this is the problem, try putting your script tag at the bottom of your page

Comment: `startTimer` should check if a timer is already running, and not start another timer if a timer was already started.

Comment: @codingStarter it 's already in the bottom 
and the console doesn't print anything

Comment: @marco-a good point, I will update the answer

Comment: @ZeiNabIbrahim you need to add more details about your code in your question in order to find the problem, this code does work for me

Comment: @codingStarter
it's work when i change the html file 
the button was in form tag , when i move it out from it ,the code work 
But i don't know why ? do you have explanation?

Comment: @codingStarter
it's work when i change the html file 
the button was in form tag , when i move it out from it ,the code work 
But i don't know why ? do you have explanation?

Comment: @mcihak it's work thank ! 
note :
 it's work when i change the html file ,the button was in form tag , when i move it out from it ,the code work But i don't know why ? do you have explanation?

Comment: bottons in form have a default event handler for the click event ("submiting" the form) - which cause the whole page to be refreash, search for have to prevent default for an event

Answer (score 1):

Update can call `setInterval()`, but, as others have pointed out, we only want at most one interval timer running. This can be expressed tersely with a [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) (not so tersely named).

Below, once  the `intervalID` has been initialized, the setInterval() will no longer be evaluated. Keeping the interval id around is useful because it allows for a stop button, also demonstrated...

```js
let intervalID;

function updateTime(run) {
  document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = (new Date()).toString()
  intervalID ??= setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
};

document
  .getElementById("btnclock")
  .addEventListener("click", updateTime);
  
document
  .getElementById("btnclock-stop")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID)
    intervalID = null;  // so the setInterval assignment can run
  });
```

```html
<button id="btnclock"> Start</button>
<p id='showtime'>&nbsp</p>
<br/>
<button id="btnclock-stop"> Stop</button>
```